# Error in MainAcitivity.java file & no style are loading

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new to android. I am creating an android application, but there are many errors showing in MainActivity.java. Here is a screenshot
[image]

Another problem is that no style in showing in activity_main.xml. Here is the screenshot
[image]

Although I have added appcompact_v7 jar file like this
[image]

But it's not recognizing it in android option of project propertise
[image]

I have installed Support library in SDK manager. Please tell me how to solve this problem?

Comment: Why are you using XP and eclipse? I think you'd better upgrade to win7/8/10 and Android Studio.

Comment: It's win7 in classical screen. I have installed eclipse before so & it's widely used by programmers, so I thought it would be better choice. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you don't need NDK, there is no reason to use eclipse. Android Studio is much more modern than eclipse, which can avoid many tedious configuration problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is really hard to say what is wrong there. here are some things that you should try:

first of all, there are errors in your xml file (activity_xml). Please check if xml is properly formatted and you are using right tags. For debugging purpose, please make your acitivity_xml an empty FrameLayout and see if it works.

Include android 6.0 into your build path. Clean the project and try building again. Make sure your layouts are error free before doing that.

Your eclipse is unable to detect referenced library at given location. Please make sure referenced library is at same place and ERROR-FREE. If library has error, your project won't include it.

Please solve all problems one by one. First make an error free xml, then a Hello world Activity. Run it on device or emulator. Once done, try to solve library and import problem now.

Best Suggestion: Please migrate to Android Studio and gradle for better support and learning.